# TypeScript Error with Zustand's Persist Middleware and StateCreator in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zustand

I'm trying to use Zustand's persist middleware to store and retrieve state in my React application. However, I'm encountering a TypeScript error that I'm struggling to resolve. The error message is as follows:

```
Argument of type 'StateCreator<ForestStore, [], [["zustand/persist", ForestStore]]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StateCreator<ForestStore, [], []>'.
Type 'StateCreator<ForestStore, [], [["zustand/persist", ForestStore]]>' is not assignable to type '{ $$storeMutators?: [] | undefined; }'.
Types of property '$$storeMutators' are incompatible.
Type '[["zustand/persist", ForestStore]] | undefined' is not assignable to type '[] | undefined'.
Type '[["zustand/persist", ForestStore]]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
Source has 1 element(s) but target allows only 0.ts(2345)
```

Here is my code:

```
import {create} from 'zustand';
import { persist, createJSONStorage} from 'zustand/middleware';

export type Forest = "poetry" | "prose" | "script";
export interface ForestStore {
  forest: Forest;
  setForest: (forest: Forest) => void;
}

const forestPersist = persist<ForestStore>(
    (set) => ({
        forest: "poetry",
        setForest: (newForest) => set(() => ({forest: newForest})),
    }),
    {
        name: "forest-storage",
        storage: createJSONStorage(() => sessionStorage),
    }
);



export const useForestStore = create<ForestStore>(forestPersist);
```

I really don't know how to solve it the code works as intended but the types are messing around.

Thanks you very much in advance

Comment: Add `()` after `create` like this: `const useForestStore = create<ForestStore>()(forestPersist)`. This will fix the type issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Muhammad Nouman Rafique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19932999/muhammad-nouman-rafique) said:

> Add () after create like this: const useForestStore = create()(forestPersist). This will fix the type issue

Answer (score 2):

Write it in this way

```
import { create, StateCreator } from "zustand";
import { persist, createJSONStorage } from "zustand/middleware";

export type Forest = "poetry" | "prose" | "script";
export interface ForestStore {
  forest: Forest;
  setForest: (forest: Forest) => void;
}

const forestSlice: StateCreator<ForestStore, [["zustand/persist", unknown]]> = (
  set
) => ({
  forest: "poetry",
  setForest: (newForest) => set(() => ({ forest: newForest })),
});

export const useForestStore = create<ForestStore>()(
  persist(forestSlice, {
    name: "forest-storage",
    storage: createJSONStorage(() => sessionStorage),
  })
);
```

If you have more middlewares like `devtools`, `immer` and `subscribeWithSelector`, you can take a look at my video, the code in this video is tested:

https://youtu.be/kTwx9NhMlzs